# Parsing twitter stdClass string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, json, parsing, twitter

I have this string stored in a database column:

```
O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:4:"type";s:5:"Point";s:11:"coordinates";a:2:{i:0;d:-23.5663719;i:1;d:-46.65284157;}}
```

And I just want the "coordinates" in the middle:

-23.5663719,-46.65284157

There is a easy way to parse it in PHP to get this value?
I tried json_decode but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not json encoded, but serialized using `serialize()`.

So what you have to do is:

```
$o = unserialize($str); // where $str is a string fetched from DB
var_dump($o->coordinates);
```

References:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Exact! I didn't know this function! Thank you!